Making a series montonically decreasing in pyspark
Say we have a pyspark dataframe that looks like



ID
Pct




1
[50,10,5,20,2]


2
[42,10, 15,5,3]



I want to add another column such that the pct column is monotonically decreasing



ID
Pct
Mon_dec_pct




1
[50,10,5,20,2]
[50,10,5,5,2]


2
[42,10, 15,5,3]
[42,10,10,5,3]



Would we be able to do this in pyspark?

Using transform,
df = (df.withColumn('Mon_dec_pct', 
                    F.expr("""
                           transform(Pct, (x, i) -> 
                                     case
                                         when i = 0 then x
                                         when Pct[i-1] > x then x 
                                         else Pct[i-1]
                                     end)
                           """)))

========================================
UPDATE
@busfighter brought up a good point.
If an array looks like [50,10,15,12,2], the simple transform doesn't work because it can only compare the value against 1 previous value.
So, you need to carry the minimum value.
This is with using the reduce to carry both the updated array and the minimum value.
df = (df.withColumn('Mon_dec_pct', 
                    F.expr("""
                           reduce(Pct, 
                                  struct(cast(array() as array<int>) as result, Pct[0] as min_val),
                                  (acc, x) -> (array_append(acc.result, least(acc.min_val, x)), 
                                               least(acc.min_val, x)),
                                  x -> x.result
                           )
                           """)))

Input
+---+-------------------+
| ID|                Pct|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|[50, 10, 15, 12, 2]|
|  2| [42, 10, 15, 5, 3]|
+---+-------------------+

Result
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
| ID|                Pct|       Mon_dec_pct |
+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|[50, 10, 15, 12, 2]|[50, 10, 10, 10, 2]|
|  2| [42, 10, 15, 5, 3]| [42, 10, 10, 5, 3]|
+---+-------------------+-------------------+


You can define a method, pass it to udf(), and then use withColumn():
import os
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, IntegerType

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = 'python3.12'
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = 'python3.12'


def get_monotonic():
    def _monotonic(L):
        for i in range(1, len(L)):
            if L[i] > L[i - 1]:
                L[i] = L[i - 1]
        return L

    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    data = [(1, [50, 10, 5, 20, 2]), (2, [42, 10, 15, 5, 3])]
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["ID", "Pct"])

    UDF = udf(_monotonic, ArrayType(IntegerType()))
    df = df.withColumn("Mon_dec_pct", UDF(col("Pct")))

    df.show(truncate=False)


get_monotonic()


Prints
+---+------------------+------------------+
|ID |Pct               |Mon_dec_pct       |
+---+------------------+------------------+
|1  |[50, 10, 5, 20, 2]|[50, 10, 5, 5, 2] |
|2  |[42, 10, 15, 5, 3]|[42, 10, 10, 5, 3]|
+---+------------------+------------------+


Generally speaking this is a dynamic problem and cannot be solved in one pass. Let's break it down:

To solve the issue with the provided example we can explode the list and then use window lag function to make it monotonic:

from pyspark.sql import Window, functions as F

df = spark_session.createDataFrame([(1, [50, 10, 5, 20, 2]), (2, [42, 10, 15, 5, 3])], ['ID', 'Pct'])
df = df.withColumn('expl', F.explode('Pct'))
df = df.withColumn('_id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
w = Window.partitionBy('ID').orderBy('_id')
df = df.withColumn('expl_lag', F.lag('expl', default='inf').over(w))
df = df.withColumn('new_expl', F.when(F.col('expl') > F.col('expl_lag'), F.col('expl_lag')).otherwise(F.col('expl')))
df = df.groupBy('ID', 'Pct').agg(F.collect_list('new_expl').alias('Mon_dec_pct'))
df.show()

# +---+------------------+------------------+
# | ID|               Pct|       Mon_dec_pct|
# +---+------------------+------------------+
# |  2|[42, 10, 15, 5, 3]|[42, 10, 10, 5, 3]|
# |  1|[50, 10, 5, 20, 2]| [50, 10, 5, 5, 2]|
# +---+------------------+------------------+


But in more general case you can have something like that:

# +---+-------------------+
# | ID|                Pct|
# +---+-------------------+
# |  2|[42, 10, 15, 12, 3]|
# |  1| [50, 10, 5, 20, 2]|
# +---+-------------------+

And the solution won't work because in one pass it can only know about the current state of the dataframe which will change after our algorithm makes a pass:
# +---+-------------------+-------------------+
# | ID|                Pct|        Mon_dec_pct|
# +---+-------------------+-------------------+
# |  2|[42, 10, 15, 12, 3]|[42, 10, 10, 12, 3]|
# |  1| [50, 10, 5, 20, 2]|  [50, 10, 5, 5, 2]|
# +---+-------------------+-------------------+

To solve that you need to rename the Mon_dec_pct -> Pct and repeat the procedure until it gets smoothed.
